# why doesnt my mysql_fetch_array or mysql_fetch_assoc does not work

Tags: php, mysql

i want to get the result of mysql query into a text, currently it works when i type  **mysql_num_fields** and **mysql_num_rows**, but it does not work **mysql_fetch_array** or **mysql_fetch_assoc** which is the genuine requirement.. can anybody kindly tell me what wrong with this code

```
$query = "CALL create_report($ID, '$startDate', '$endDate', $endlmt, $position);";

    $Localcon = $this->getConnection();
    $result = mysql_query($query, $Localcon);
    //$debug = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $myFile = "debug.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = "-------------\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    $stringData = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
```

edited code

```
$stringData_2 = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    foreach ($stringData_2 as $string) {
        $stringData = "----------------\n";
        fwrite($fh, $stringData);
        fwrite($fh, $string);
    }
```

Comment: `$result = mysql_query($query, $Localcon) or die(mysql_error($Localcon));`

Comment: [Deprecated features in PHP 5.5.x - ext/mysql deprecation](http://php.net/manual/migration55.deprecated.php#migration55.deprecated.mysql)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) returns an array, while [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) is expecting a string. Here is the error your code produces:

```
fwrite() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in ...
```

The 2 param of fwrite, `$stringData`, needs to be a string.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you might start by trying something like this, then play around with other alternatives:

```
...
foreach($result as $str) {
    fwrite($fh, $str);
}
...
```

---

*Sidenote:* [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: `print_r($result);` and make sure it contains what you think. Then check that `fwrite` works by passing a single, simple string.